# Extract XML data from ajax result

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xml

My AJAX call is like this

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/services/LTLGadgetV2.aspx',
    type: 'Get',
    success: function (result) {      
        console.log( result);  }
    });
```

In the console I get this as a result:

[image]
Sample XML

```
  <RateResults xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<PriceSheets>
  <PriceSheet type="Cost" CurrencyCode="USD" CreateDate="0001-01-01T00:00:00">
    <LaneID>9553</LaneID>
    <MaxDeficitWeight>19999</MaxDeficitWeight>
  </PriceSheet>
</PriceSheets>
<StatusCode>0</StatusCode>
<StatusMessage>Rating Process completed with no errors</StatusMessage>
<debug>
  <debug>
    <ContractName>2013  Pinnacpccle </ContractName>
  </debug>
</debug>
<PricingModel><![CDATA[<div id="PricingModelDiv" style="position:absolute;display:none;"><table id="myTable" Width = "300" style="font-family:Verdana; background:white; font-size:9" border="1"> </table></div>]]></PricingModel>
</RateResults>
```

Can anyone please point out how I could get the XML data inside this response so that I can make operations on it? I want to parse the output to proper XML like this

```
   var xmlDocNp;
    xmlDocNp = $.parseXML('<xml>' + result + '</xml>'),
     $xml = $(xmlDocNp),
    pricingModel = $xml.find('PricingModel').text();
```

But in order to do it, I first need to extract only XML data from above result

> Note: the XML data starts from `RateResults` tag

```
Note: If i put a break-point and checked the result in chrome, it looks like this
```

[image]

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Updated my question with asked details

Comment: tried? `dataType: "xml",`

Comment: With short version of provided XML it seems to work in [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zq02L8a6/).

Comment: @Regent please note the '#document' ins the console

Comment: the #document is not in your response, that's simply the browser's console making it clear to you "what follows is a document".

Comment: @Athul just write `console.log($xml[0]);` in provided fiddle, and you will see the same `#document`, described by funkwurm.

Comment: @Regent XMl is same, But I getting null as pricingModel with this code

Comment: You don't need those extra `<xml>` -> [http://jsfiddle.net/lshettyl/bma5nf4j/](http://jsfiddle.net/lshettyl/bma5nf4j/)

Comment: @Athul either there is something wrong/incorrect in XML (which didn't get into fiddle) or error in some other place (code).

Comment: @Regent I have updated my question with little more data, please take a look

Comment: @LShetty I have updated my question with little more data, please take a look

Comment: @Athul can you post `result` value as text? I mean `<RateResults xmlns:` and so on.

Comment: @Athul yes, full XML still works in [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zq02L8a6/1/) in   Opera 29.0. Same story with Firefox 37.0.2. XML looks like valid one.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80272/discussion-between-athul-and-regent).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `result` is already `Object`, not a `String`, there is no need to use `$.parseXML()`:

```
var $xml = $(result);
var pricingModel = $xml.find('PricingModel').text();
```

The reason for this is that even if you don't set `dataType` of result data in Ajax request parameters, jQuery uses *Intelligent Guess* to understand what the data is. Since jQuery has correctly guessed that it is XML, it executed `$.parseXML()` internally and passed `Object` instead of `String` to `success` callback.

[jQuery.ajax() docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/services/LTLGadgetV2.aspx",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: xmlParser
   });
});

function xmlParser(xml) {
    console.log($(xml).find('PricingModel'))
}
```

working example: http://jsbin.com/famemidoli/1/edit?js,console,output